# how to get 0-10 V output from Op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, circuit-design

I have made this circuit:

[image: OpAmp circuit]

The idea of this circuit is to convert 0-3.3V(vdc0) input to 0-10V output. I have tested the circuit both in a simulator and in real life. In the simulator it worked. In real life it is another story..: I input 3.3V and get 10V output. But the output can only go down to 6V and not lower. Why is that? Is it something to do with some bias current from output through R1? I have tripple checked my wiring though..
I use a [LM1458](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm1458.pdf) as OpAmp. 
Can anyone give me a hint to where i can find the answer?

Comment: This is one of the hardest to read schematics for a non-inverting op-amp I have seen. I think the problem might be that the LM1458 is a dual supply op-amp but you only supply +15V to VCC and 0V to VEE, not -15V to the VEE.

Comment: The reason single-supply vs dual supply matters, is that the inverting and non-inverting inputs (and the output) need to be several volts away from the VCC and VEE rails (unless the op-amp is specifically a rail-to-rail op-amp, and even then it's best not to operate too close to the supply rail limits).

Comment: That is true but only when you use simple opamps. If you would use an opamp with "rail-to-rail" inputs and outputs it would work. An example of such an opamp is the MCP6001.

Comment: Check the datasheet Electrical Characteristics, under `Input Voltage Range` they only guarantee +/- 12V input when supply is +/- 15V, which means the inputs must be at least 3V above VEE and 3V below VCC. So in your case with 15V single-supply, the inputs must be between 3V and 12V.

Comment: maybe helpful: [Single supply or dual supply op-amp](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2962/opamps-single-supply-or-dual)

Answer (score 1):

On a +/- 15V supply the input range of the op-amp is +/- 12V. Inputs are disallowed within 3V of the power rails.

This means that a supply regime of 0V and 15V disallows inputs outside the range 3V to 12V.

Same story for output voltage swing. Only +/-12V is guaranteed for +/-15V rails. It's a pretty common story for most op-amps.

Comment: but he only needs 10V

Comment: @Jasen what are you talking about dude - he needs 0V to 10V on the output.

Comment: only needs pull-up though.

Comment: The worst case scenario is when the output is "asked" to produce 0V on the output - there is no R2R op-amp that can get much below 50mV. The LM324 is only guaranteed to get down to 50mV and if you have a pull-up (to help the upper boundary) then the ground capabilities are severely affected.

Comment: I mean that the op amp only need to pull upwards on the load, it only needs to source current, not sink any.

Comment: "disallows inputs in the range 3V to 12V." - I think you mean, only allows inputs in the range 3v to 12v?

Comment: @NickJohnson -oops and fixed.

Answer (score 0):

For this application you need an op-amp where the input range includes the negative supply

rail-to-rail output is not needed as the output only ever sources current and is never  asked to go closer than 5V to the positive supply.

LM324 looks good in this application.

Comment: The data sheet for the LM324 indicates that the output is guaranteed to go as low as 50mV above ground with a 10k load on the output. It's good but not that good. This will be the problem faced by this or any R2R output device. The question is how close to the 0V rail is acceptable?

Comment: LM324 is mainly famous for being cheap. but it does have several other nice qualities.

Comment: at 50mv that's unliklely to be visible on a 10V moving-coil meter, about 0.5 degree deflection,  but I don't know that that' the application here.

Comment: I will try out the LM324. I can see from the datasheet that it requires a supply voltage of either 32V or +-16V. Due to the fact that i only need a output of 0-10V is it possible to supply it with VCC = 15V and VEE = GND? or will this not be enough for the LMM324?